# Opening Up Facebook app outside Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, filepicker.io

I have a web app which I am loading in Facebook iframes. The thing is my app opens File Picker which sends backs the data form where it was loaded. But if my web app is inside an iframe it doesn't allow File picker to communicate back due to security reasons.

So what I am doing it when the users on my FB page click on my app I take them out of the facebook and open my web app in browser. This thing works perfectly in Android or on my Windows. But in Iphone it doesn't takes the app outside and doesn't open it in the browser.

Do you know why? Is there a solution for it?

Comment: What do you mean with "in iPhone"? Fb app?; m.facebook.com in Safari? What exactly happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the problem is a security feature of the browser's popup blocker. 
It treats the window as a popup if it occurs outside of the callback of a user interaction.
It therefore gets buckets as a popup and blocked. 
Unfortunately, iOS Safari gives absolutely no indication of this, making the issue difficult to track down.