# Ink Filepicker broken with wall links from the Facebook IOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook, cross-domain, filepicker.io

When posting a link to our web site to someones Facebook wall, the ink file picker stops working when the person uses the Facebook IOS application.

The file picker comes up and works normally, but as soon as you try to submit the image, the error in the attached screenshot appears below appears.

The text is cut off but it is something like "...results to application. Communication iframe...".

All works fine in the android FB application which clearly opens links in an external browser.  But with the FB IOS, our web site seems to render inside the FB app through some sort of deep linking magic.  It seems clear that this is some sort of cross domain issue that has been recently introduced by changes at FB.

Has anyone come across this?  Any workarounds?

[image]

This question may be related to this one here:

[Opening Up Facebook app outside Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24287646/opening-up-facebook-app-outside-facebook)

Comment: I have a similar problem but not related to iOS but just with using an iframe, would be good to get some clarity on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full message is "Cannot send results to the application. Communication iframe not found.. Please close this window and try again." (should be responsive)

Filepicker isn't able to communicate when it is run inside FB IOS app. A solution might be to force it to display filepicker in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the full error, that'll help with debugging.  I'm surprised no one from filepicker is monitoring this thread.  I haven't had any luck in reaching their tech support, all the emails are bouncing. How would you open filepicker in a separate browser?

Comment: It would appear this is more related to FilePicker.io not supporting "embedded" browsers (or issues with `iframe` communication). I am trying to implement this in a Delphi app and I can get as far as authenticating/authorising the app but after that I get the same error above.

Comment: There's a note from Filepicker about this message: https://developers.filepicker.io/docs/support/issues/68 -- they say they have no workaround. Not useful.

Comment: We've stopped using Filepicker.  The html 5 image upload field with the ability to access the camera is working fine for us.  We moved our image hosting to cloudinary as well.